# Is Font awesome pro 5.13.0 backward compatible?

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I am using font-awesome version 4.7.0 in my web application. I decided to buy a font-awesome pro. Can I add font-awesome pro 5.13.0 to my app and remove the early font-awesome version 4.7.0 from my app?
Will that break any existing icons I used from font-awesome version 4.7.0?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's. You have the ability to configure your kit to enable the V4.

Here is a screenshot showing the configuration:

[image]

More details here too: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4#kits

---

By the way, I advice you to wait and buy the V6 that will be released soon: https://fontawesome.com/6